# Is there another way to define $T^t$ (transpose transformation)?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

In linear algebra, I know the tradition way to define the transpose transformation $T^t$ of a linear transformation $T$. And we can show that $[T^t]_{\gamma *,\beta *}=([T]_{\beta,\gamma})^t$. However, though the construction/definition of $T^t$ gives the "right" thing we somehow want a transpose be, I just think that there are always lack of reason that this is the only choice we've got. Couldn't we define $T^t$ from $W$ to $V$, rather than $W^*\to V^*$? Couldn't we define a more easy function?

If we can't, have anyone proved that the traditional definition of $T^t$ is actually almost the "best" way we can do? Are there other ways to define transpose transformations? I'm also curious about how did this definition discovered in the history. Maybe it can suggest some clues.

Comment: In the real context, it's the adjoint, which is helpful ehen wirking with inner products. But in the complex conext, it's not, which makes it a bit unnatural.

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks. One question, do you misplace the word "real" and "complex"?

Comment: I don't think so, but I was thinking about matrices a bit too much for your question. In any case, the Hermitian adjoint is basically the thing you want (from $W$ to $V$), as described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_of_a_linear_map#Relation_to_the_Hermitian_adjoint